# How to calculate force needed in order for a ball to hit a specific point $(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Hey I'm trying to build a 3D game and In the game a ball gets thrown forward to a specific spot. I am trying to figure out based on the balls starting spot it $(x,y,z)$ relative to the spot that its trying to throw to. How much force left or right and forward or backward will it have to apply to the ball in order for the ball to enough force to reach its destination. I'm looking for a equation in plan English.

Things I think would need to be in the equation:

```
  • Ball mass like = 1
  • ballStartingSpot starting location Vector/Cordinates( x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
  • ballEndingSpot -ending location Vector/Cordinates( x: -50.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
  • Gravity which is has a Vector/Cordinates( x: 0.0, y: -9.8, z: 0.0) 

  • force needs to be applied which would be a Vector/Cordinates( x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
```

This SWIFT code below lets me calculate how much force needs to be applied in order for the ball to be thrown foward with the corrcet amount of force everytime. but know i just need it to calculate how much left and right it would need aswell

Code:

```
         func ballisticVelocity(projectile:SCNNode, target: SCNVector3, angle: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
        let origin = projectile.presentationNode.position
        var dir = target - origin       // get target direction
        let h = dir.y                  // get height difference
        dir.y = 0                      // retain only the horizontal direction
        var dist = dir.length()         // get horizontal distance
        dir.y = dist * tan(angle)       // set dir to the elevation angle
        dist += h / tan(angle)          // correct for small height differences
        // calculate the velocity magnitude
        let vel = sqrt(dist * -scnView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity.y / sin(2 * angle))
        return dir.normalized() * vel * Float(projectile.physicsBody!.mass)
    }
```

Basically these are examples of what I think you'd need be I'm really looking for a solid simple equation that doesn't have to be in code. Thanks.

Comment: sorry to tell, but you should study physics before immersing yourself in the code

Comment: Sorry this is not my Code Its pulled from a website but is test and works perfect. Do you know the equation that im supposed to use? @G Cab

Answer (score 2):

So let me try and put you on the .."right trajectory".
Assume that the "model" of reference is that of a ball, actioned by a launching mechanism (tennis player, rifle, etc. etc.) 
impressing a certain amount of kinetic energy, in a certain direction. 
After the ball leaves the mechanism, e.g. at $t=0$, it is subject to a "free flight" , i.e. no action (wind, air drag etc.) other than gravity:
a constant acceleration of value $g$ directed in the $-y$ direction (as per your choice of the axes).
Now

- the trajectory of the ball, after it has been thrown, depends on the initial **velocity** , and does not depend on the mass of the ball.
- the initial velocity in turn will depend on the **force** applied during the launching phase before $t=0$, and on for how much time it is applied, and on the mass of the ball.
- the trajectory remains in the "vertical" plane in which the ball is initially launched, i.e. 
  the plane through the launching point, parallel to the $y$ axis  and parallel to initial (and subsequent) velocity vector.
- to be hit, the target point *must be in the trajectory plane*; when it is in that plane, there is an infinite number of trajectories hitting it
- in that plane the euclidean coordinates are $d = \sqrt {x^2  + z^2 } $ and $y$.
  Then, given $\mathbf{v}_0  = \left( {v_{0,\,d} ,v_{0,\,y} } \right)$ you have:
  $$
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
    0 \leqslant t \hfill \\
    d = v_{0,\,d} \,t \hfill \\
    y = v_{0,\,y} \,t - \frac{1}
  {2}g\,t^2  \hfill \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right.
  $$
  that is:
  $$
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
    \text{sign}\left( d \right) = \text{sign}\left( {v_{0,\,d} } \right) \hfill \\
    2\,v_{0,\,d} ^2 \,y - 2\,d\,v_{0,\,y} \,\,v_{0,\,d}  + g\,d^2  = 0 \hfill \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right.
  $$
  which is a quadratic equation in the four parameters $d,\;y,\;v_{0,\,d} ,\;v_{0,\,y} $.
  Fixing two of them, you can determine a relation between the remaining two
  that will result in hitting the target. 
  Because of the quadratic nature of the equation, you will find certain bounds
  in the existence of solutions, which also have physical evidence.  E.g. you can never hit
  a target that is above the shooting aiming direction, and so on.